# Remove New Line at the beginning and '-' from the contents of file

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, string-manipulation

I have a file with the below output.

> ---------- PFIZ_EXT_SEAGRCLMHISD_20141013_1.TXT: 165428
>
> ---------- PFIZ_EXT_SEBMODCHKIND_20141013_1.TXT: 0
>
> ---------- PFIZ_EXT_SECNSLDND_20141013_1.TXT: 13
>
> ---------- PFIZ_EXT_SECNSMRD_20141013_1.TXT: 15788
>
> ---------- PFIZ_EXT_SECNSNTD_20141013_1.TXT: 291825
>
> ---------- PFIZ_EXT_SECPGNPRD_20141013_1.TXT: 24129
>
> ---------- PFIZ_EXT_SEFFLD_20141013_1.TXT: 219599
>
> ---------- PFIZ_EXT_SESVYRSPD_20141013_1.TXT: 123284

Can you please help me in removing the new line at the beginning and '-' from this file?

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```
for /f "tokens=2,3" %a in (file.txt) do @echo %a%b >> file2.txt
```

it will remove the `-` part and the space between the file name, and number and then write the output to another file

ps:

i guess it was `find`'s output, huh?

Comment: right :) it is find's output. But the above syntax is giving me an output as 'Echo is On' :(. Need suggestions

Comment: ps: review my post, `>>` part corrected. if still doesn't work then remove `@`, and if you put this code into a batch file, prepend an extra `%` to `for` variables (`%%a` and `%%a%%b`).

Comment: lovely :) it's working now - after i replaced with (%%a and %%a%%b)

Comment: if the code worked for you consider accepting the answer to be done with the question :p

Answer (score 0):

**I already answered this in your previous [question](https://superuser.com/questions/825435/windows-batch-file-to-copy-and-count-file-names-and-output-to-single-file/825451#825451).**

Reference [FIND Search for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html)

```
find /v /c "" *.* > result.txt
```

**How it works**

- `/v` inverts the search (so when we search for nothing we find all
  lines)
- `/c` counts matches
- `""` match nothing
- `*.*` search all files
- `> result.txt` redirect output

**Limitations**

- assumes normal windows end of line delimeters `\r\n`
- although FIND can be used to scan large files, it will not detect any string that is positioned more than 1070 characters along a single line (with no carriage return `\r`) This makes it of limited use in searching binary or XML file types.

To remove the additional <kbd>-</kbd> and blank lines we can wrap the above command in a `for` construct as follows:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2-3" %a in (`find /v /c "" *.*`) do echo %a %b >> result.txt
```